# Column name same as spark data type issue

Tags: oracle, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have a table with column name "interval" which is a kind of data type in spark 3 , while processing the table data we are failing due to this issue ,we cannot rename the column name as it is from different source location, any suggestion on this please.

i tried replace in interval with _interval it is working fine and for ingestion we  are using nifi it is working on it, but while processing the data using spark 3 other than column name as interval it is working.
column name should be same as source while we keep table in destination locatn.

Comment: First, it is best to add code so that we can see what you are talking about.  Yes, certain names are reserved words and certain file formats such as parquet have rules such as not spaces.  Second, did you try escaping the column name with [ ] ??

Answer (score 0):

While there may be a workaround in Spark, if your source database is Oracle (you tagged Oracle) you can also fix this on the database side. You can rename any column at query time simply by aliasing it:

```
SELECT col1, col2, "INTERVAL" interval_renamed
  FROM table
```

And if your tool doesn't allow that, you can also create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS
SELECT col1,col2, "INTERVAL" interval_renamed
  FROM table
```

Application does:

```
SELECT * FROM my_view
```

P.S. interval is also a keyword in Oracle, so make sure to enclose it in double-quotes like I showed here.